# What's the proper way to use the MediaPlayer in Android for multiple sounds?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have multiple raw sounds that I want to play at user input. I use the example from the documentation:

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.sound_file_1);
mediaPlayer.start();
```

But since I have multiple sounds, should I do MediaPlayer.create(...) each time I want to play a different sound, or should I instantiate multiple MediaPlayer objects and just call start() on which I want to play?

I guess I'm asking the cost of instantiating when needed vs keeping in memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use multiple small sounds, it's actually better to use [SoundPool](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html) instead:

```
AudioAttributes audioAttributes = AudioAttributes.Builder()
            .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
            .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_GAME)
            .build();

SoundPool soundPool = new SoundPool.Builder()
            .setAudioAttributes(audioAttributes)
            .build();

int id = soundPool.load(context, resourceId, 0);
soundPool.play(id, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
```

But if you really need an answer to my question, I would say you should keep the MediaPlayer in memory, instantiating it on the run will slow down your app and delay the sound.